# Is there a Ruby on Rails site thumbnail generator available?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thumbnails, generator

I'm hoping to avoid building this if it already exists.  Does anyone know of a plugin for Ruby on Rails that will generate a screenshot of a web site?  Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me find one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I am aware you need a server with a desktop (eg. Gnome, X11, KDE) and a web browser with thumbnail capabilities installed (eg. webkit and [CutyCapt](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/)). Of course this is not usual for a Linux server.

I have used the service suggested by Soufiane using code based on Peter Coopers snippet and it works very well.

Generating website thumbnails would require significant server resources and some sort of background process and job queue so using a [web thumbnail generation service](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/10-free-website-thumbnail-generation-services/) might be a better alternative to generating your own.

Comment: Anyone else looking at this might also want to check out "PDFKit":https://github.com/jdpace/PDFKit

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is a wonderful solution:

http://webthumb.bluga.net/

It has an great API and there are some Ruby Wrappers (i.e. http://github.com/simplificator/rwebthumb)

It allows you to process 100 thumbnails a month, if you need more the price for credits is very generous if you ask me.

Comment: Hey http://webthumb.bluga.net/ is good service. But somehow it takes time to load the image & we can not figure out why it is taking that much time. When we started using the service the time to create the thumbnail was 3-4 secs, but now it is 10-12 secs. We also bought the paid version for the service & still having the same issue. Please let me know anything extra rather than this is needed to keep it working properly.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a plugin, but I found [this snippet](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/3621) which is using an external site to do what you want (I think.). I didn't test it though.

Answer (score 0):

This is getting a little dated now, but just for posterity's sake there is an answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9449065#22418971)