# How do I generate website thumbnails without 3rd party tools?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, thumbnails

Are there any gems out there for Rails 3.2.1 that generate website thumbnails? I see a lot of 3rd party solutions but I don't like the fact that they aren't hosted on my server. It's really important the app I'm building is as stable as possible and I think this is not a good solution in the long run.

My ruby knowledge is fairly good, I think enough to use a gem and implement it, but definitely not good enough to write something like this from scratch if no gems exist.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want thumbnails of images? (If so, this is easy: see the dragonfly gem for example) Or do you want a programmatically render a Web site and save the image as a thumbnail? (If so, this is harder.)

Comment: You say "it's really important the app I'm building is as stable as possible." Ok. It doesn't follow that third party services are going to be less reliable. In many (if not most) cases, they will be more reliable that what you build.

Comment: a gem which does the same job on my own server and only relies on the variables of my own environment to me is better than a service using x thousand more lines of code, and needs to distribute to thousands of users and have 100% uptime.

Comment: I think the "better" solution, pragmatically, is one that works, is easily maintainable, and let's you focus on your value add -- not based on any preconceived notions of lines of code, where the solution is hosted, and so on. In any case, what did you decide on? (and could you please reply to my first comment -- your question is unclear)

Comment: I would like to render out images of the entire website. After tons and tons of searching though I think I'm going to go with https://url2png.com/

Comment: Ive looked at phantomjs and all kinds of solutions like that. I'm just going to stick with url2png as it looks fairly straightfoward. what i DO want to do though is save the file to my own server once it fetches it, as the image expires after a month and counts towards your total monthly renders once it redraws the same image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://url2png.com/ has worked great so far

Answer (score 2):

You could try [dragonfly](https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly) or [carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave)

Comment: I'm not sure if Tallboy wants "just" an image thumbnail generation gem or if he wants a tool that can snapshot (screenshot) a rendered Web page.

Comment: @DavidJames, upon reading the title, yes, that could be the case :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, here's the first thing that came up on Rubygems: [thumbnailer](http://thumbnail.rubyforge.org/). It uses Amazon and costs a small fee per image it generates, so you probably don't want this...

<strike>But there's also [thumbnailer-ruby](https://rubygems.org/gems/thumbnailer-ruby) which looks like it works completely on the local machine. Haven't tested it out, though.</strike> It appears that this doesn't actually do what you want. Nevermind.

Now another gem called [snapurl](https://rubygems.org/gems/snapurl) looks pretty fancy. Once again, I haven't tried it out yet. I'll do that now.

EDIT: Won't run for me; keeps failing with an error.

Comment: thumbnailer relies on the [now-defunct Amazon Alexa thumbnailer service](http://aws.amazon.com/ast/). That's why it doesn't work. "The Alexa Site Thumbnail web service has been deprecated and is no longer available for new subscriptions."

Answer (score 0):

a[Browshot](http://browshot.com/) has a [gem available](https://rubygems.org/gems/browshot).

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use a third party service for this. 
You can do something like this in your model:

```
class MySexyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  ... stuff

  # Generate the thumbnail on validate so we can return errors on failure
  validate :generate_thumbnail_from_url

  # Cleanup temp files when we are done
  after_save :cleanup_temp_thumbnail

  # Generate a thumbnail from the remote URL
  def generate_thumbnail_from_url

    # Skip thumbnail generation if:
    # a) there are already other validation errors
    # b) an image was manually specified
    # c) an image is already stored and the URL hasn't changed
    skip_generate = self.errors.any? || (self.image_changed? ||
        (self.image_stored? && !self.url_changed?))
    # p "*** generating thumbnail: #{!skip_generate}"
    return if skip_generate

    # Generate and assign an image or set a validation error
    begin
      tempfile = temp_thumbnail_path
      cmd = "wkhtmltoimage --quality 95 \"#{self.url}\" \"#{tempfile}\""
      # p "*** grabbing thumbnail: #{cmd}"
      system(cmd) # sometimes returns false even if image was saved
      self.image = File.new(tempfile) # will throw if not saved
    rescue => e
      # p "*** thumbnail error: #{e}"
      self.errors.add(:base, "Cannot generate thumbnail. Is your URL valid?")
    ensure
    end
  end

  # Return the absolute path to the temporary thumbnail file
  def temp_thumbnail_path
    File.expand_path("#{self.url.parameterize.slice(0, 20)}.jpg", Dragonfly.app.datastore.root_path)
  end

  # Cleanup the temporary thumbnail image
  def cleanup_temp_thumbnail
    File.delete(temp_thumbnail_path) rescue 0
  end
end
```

The original post is on this blog: [http://sourcey.com](http://sourcey.com/generating-website-thumbnails-in-rails-using-dragonfly-and-wkhtmltoimage/)

Comment: Please don't just post a link-only answer, but also include relevant details.

Comment: Thank you sir, glad to be here :)